# Which constructor should be used in FinalityFlow if there are no counterparties?

Tags: corda

Starting in Corda 4 there is a deprecation warning when using the FinalityFlow(SignedTransaction) constructor stating "constructor FinalityFlow(SignedTransaction)' is deprecated. It is unsafe to use this constructor as it requires nodes to automatically accept notarised transactions without first checking their relevancy. Instead, use one of the constructors that requires only FlowSessions."

What is the best practice if there are no counterparties and we just need to issue a state into our own vault? Would we want to create a flow session with ourselves or just use the deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same, just pass an empty list for the counterparties:

```
return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(signedTx, Collections.emptyList()));
```